# Exposing Neo4J REST within TomCat

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an SDN 2.3.1 application running 1.9 Neo4J embedded which is deployed on Tomcat 7. All good when running both embedded and rest. However, I'm now looking to try and expose the REST interface having followed [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111959/use-wrappingneoserverbootstrapper-with-spring-data-neo4j) so that I cuse Linkurious to explore the embedded data.

The exception I get on deployment is:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
```

My XML config is

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${neo4j.datastore}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>
```

I have the static-web and neo4j-server in my pom.xml

My guess is it's a conflict with Jetty and Tomcat around who's allowed to deploy to a context. Is my config even possible and if so, what step might I be missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper with spring-data-neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111959/use-wrappingneoserverbootstrapper-with-spring-data-neo4j)

Comment: I wish, but makes no diff... If stand-alone neo4j server is running, the embedded service wisely tells me that the port is in use. If the SA server is not running, then I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing transitive dependency on Jersey which I didn't spot in documentation.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The web admin interface is throwing an exception but I can at least run embedded and expose a RESTful interface to Neo4J- Yay!

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662919/jersey-no-webapplication-provider-is-present-when-jersey-json-dependency-added) for the pointer